# Is there any way to turn on Advancement in Minecraft Bedrock by modifying the world file?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, achievements

I accidentally turned on creative mode, which means I cannot get any Advancement in my world now. Is there any way to turn the advancement back on?